# I am getting StaleElementReferenceException. how can i resolve this issue in below case

Tags: selenium

'''
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//NaqDaq//Downloads//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

```
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");

    List<WebElement> linksList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    linksList.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")));

    System.out.println("The full size of Links and Images are: " + linksList.size());

    List<WebElement> activeLinks = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

    for(int i=0; i<linksList.size(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(linksList.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
        if(linksList.get(i).getAttribute("href") != null) {
            activeLinks.add(linksList.get(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The active links and images are--->" + activeLinks.size());
```

'''

Comment: using above code i am trying to find broken links

Answer (score 0):

Vishal,

Try the below code, it worked for me.

```
@Test(enabled = true)
public static void amazonActiveLinks() {

    // Browser Initializing
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Software\\geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");

    List<WebElement> linksList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
    linksList.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")));
    System.out.println("The full size of Links and Images are: " + linksList.size());

    String url;
    List<WebElement> activeLinks = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

    for (WebElement link : linksList) {
        url = link.getAttribute("href");
        if (url != null || url != "") {
            activeLinks.add(link);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The active links and images are--->" + activeLinks.size());

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Prashanth, but in my system TestNG is also not working I am getting below error in console when I execute script :-

Comment: [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Stage
 at org.testng.internal.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:33)
 at org.testng.TestNG.init(TestNG.java:216)
 at org.testng.TestNG.<init>(TestNG.java:200)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.<init>(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:17)
 at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.<init>(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:18)

Comment: Can you plz help me in this

Comment: Delete @Test annotation and add the below code


 public static void main(String[] args){ 
  amazonActiveLinks(); 
  }
}